# How can I freeze motion with a high shutter speed in low light?

Tags: slowmotion

I'm trying to film guitar strings moving. So, I'm putting high shutters peed (1/1000) and slow frame rate (25). This is working. But the problem is when I'm doing it in the evening. The image is to dark. I'm putting iso up to the limit and open the lens to the maximum.

Is the only solution to put more light??

Comment: This is typically done with a [stroboscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscope) synced to the frame rate.

Comment: Yes. 'The only solution to put more light', so 1/1000 of a sec collects enough to create an image from it. You can put more light by strobes or flashes, or just switch another lamp on, but _you need more light_

Comment: Maybe use a faster lens?  If you're using a compatible lens mount, you could try a metabones speedbooster.  Aperture, shutter, ISO, ND, actual light.  Those are the 5 things you can change.

Comment: Thx guys, i think i'll go with additional lamp/spotlight. As i'm not a professional movie maker, I'll not invest in extra hardware.

Comment: "Is the only solution to put more light?" - you can get a more sensitive camera like the Sony a7s. As an a side, 25 fps at 1/1000 would be hard to watch.

Comment: Put on more light and darken the shot in post production

Answer (score -1):

> "Is the only solution to put more light??".

No.

This is explained here and many other places: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle .

There are three ways, the three factors are:

- Shutter — how long you let light in
- Aperture — how large of an opening you let light through (how much at once)
- ISO — how sensitive your film or sensor is to light

Half the Shutter Speed will double the brightness, a lens with a larger Aperture will let in more light but also reduces the Depth of Field and is more expensive, finally a camera with a more sensitive sensor will also result in a brighter image at a greater cost.

Reducing the Shutter Speed is likely the better method if you want the strings to have a bit of blur and depict motion. IF you actually wanted tack sharp frames of the strings moving you would not want to film at 25FPS but instead at a very high Frame Rate.

Do you need to do this only in the evening?, if most of the Film is set in the evening then do a few closeups during the day and use multiple lights to remove all shadows and increase the light so it's extremely bright; film that and rely upon the darkening of the fast Shutter to make it appear dark.

Comment: As it is stated in the question the aperture is set to max and the iso also. Shutter and FPS are set to these values to achive the effect.